# Regular expressions in preg_match pattern not matching string

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I've read the [PHPManual RegEx Intro](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.introduction.php), but am confused on how to structure the pattern for preg_match. I am checking that the username on the login form is all lower case alphabet between 2 and 5 characters in length.

**Pattern 1**: Initially, I used a character class followed by a repetition quantifier:

```
if (preg_match("[a-z]{2,5}",$_POST['ULusername'])) {
    $formmessage = 'Hello, ' . $_POST['ULusername'];
} else {
    $formmessage = 'Enter username.';
}
```

The output was always "Enter username."

**Pattern 2**: I then thought perhaps I needed delimiters:

```
if (preg_match("/[a-z]{2,5}/",$_POST['ULusername'])) {
    $formmessage = 'Hello, ' . $_POST['ULusername'];
} else {
    $formmessage = 'Enter username.';
}
```

But the output was still always "Enter username."

**Pattern 3**: Finally, I tried delimiters with the begin/end anchors:

```
if (preg_match("#^([a-z]{2,5})$#",$_POST['ULusername'])) {
    $formmessage = 'Hello, ' . $_POST['ULusername'];
} else {
    $formmessage = 'Enter username.';
}
```

This gave me the desired output.

Why does the third pattern work, but not the first two?

Answer (score 0):

The first pattern returns false, an indication that an error occurred (here, no delimiter in pattern).

The second and third patterns are valid regex patterns but they do not match the same set of strings. Using `"/[a-z]{2,5}/"` you'd have a match whenever `$_POST['ULusername']` *contains* at least two consecutive lowercase characters. However, it does not care if the length of the whole string is greater than 5.

The last pattern both has delimiters and a *start and end anchors*, so only lowercase strings of length 2 to 5 will match.

Comment: I see. I misunderstood how the quantifier works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. The first one fails because it doesn't contain a delimiter.
2. In the second one, there is a problem in your logic. Because `/[a-z]{2,5}/` check only two to five consecutive lower case letters only. And there is no indication of input length in there. Try it with `ABcdEF`, then you'll understand what's going on there.
3. In the third one first, you grouped this pattern `[a-z]{2,5}` using `()` and check whether that given string starts and ends with this `([a-z]{2,5})` group pattern. But according to my tests of your third code, the grouping doesn't affect your logic. Try it without `()` and you will get the same result. Because when you group the logic `[a-z]{2,5}` and check whether a given string starts and ends with that group is same as `#^[a-z]{2,5}$#`.

For more information, you can refer tutorials about regular expressions.

http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html

https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html

Comment: Very clear explanations of all three. And good links. thanks!